# Mass of a Tetrahedron finding bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, iterated-integrals

### In a question about finding the mass of a Tetrahedron[image: work]

The question given is this:
Find the mass of a tetrahedron with corners at (0,0,0),(π/4, π/4, 0), (0, π/4, π/4), and (0, π/4, 0) whose density at point (x,y,z) is sin(x).

Recall that the mass of a region is the integral of the density function over the region.

Give your answer as an exact expression.

---

I really just guessed the bounds based off a similar question.  How do I actually go about finding these bounds? I can't visualize this object very well and I am not to sure how to draw something like (π/4, π/4, 0), (0, π/4, π/4), (0, π/4, 0).

Could someone maybe describe the process of finding the bounds? The actual integration steps are straightforward.

Comment: What is the actual question? Please post it in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathbb{P}: x+y+z = \frac{\pi}{4} \rightarrow z = \frac{\pi}{4} - x - y
$$
$$
\mbox{XY}: y = -x + \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
$$
m=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}-x}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}-x-y}\rho(x,y,z)dzdydx
$$